# How to set ANdroid app audio volume programmatically

Tags: java, android, media-player

I am trying, unsuccessfully, to set the audio volume of an Android audio player to 100%.

I have an Android app, in Java, that runs on an Android device. The device is a Khadas VIM3L which has an attached tone board, and a touchscreen.
The VIM3L is running Android 9.0 (Pie).

I am trying to set the media volume to 100%, or at least something large like 75%.
The client is then adding hardware to the output of the tone board.
I don’t know all the details.

Anyway, with my current setup (Khadas VIM3L, tone board, touchscreen) the default output seems to be about 25%.
So I am trying to change this.

When the app is launched, it displays a trakclist of songs.
Clicking on a track, will then play that track.
When the track completes, it will start the second track, etc.

First, I tried just using the Android settings – setting the volume to 100% and the media volume to 100%.
However, when I restarted the device, the volume is back to about 25%.

I then added some Java code to set the volume to 100%.

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
int volumeLevel = 100; // Adjust this as needed
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, volumeLevel, 0);
```

I have added this code to the main activity on launch.
I have also added to the code that runs when the play button is clicked, when the next track is played, etc.

The general observation is this:
When I install the app and then run it – the volume is set to 100% for the first track.
If I power cycle the device and launch the app again, and play the first track, the volume is at the default 25%. When  first track finishes, and the second track starts, the volume is set to 100%.

Here are my observations:

**Scenario 1**

> App incudes Java code to set media volume to 100%
>
> Install the app and launch – volume is at 100%
>
> Close the ap, relaunch – volume is still at 100%
>
> Restart the device, launch the app – volume is at 20%

**Scenario 2**

> Restart the device, touch the volume controls on the touchscreen
>
> A warning is displayed:
>
> Raise volume above recommended level?  Listening at high volume for
> long periods may damage your hearing.  CANCEL /       OK
>
> Without clicking on anything, launch the app – the volume is at 100%

It seems that the very fact that this warning was displayed, allows the app to set the volume to 100%

**Scenario 3**

> Restart the device, launch the app – volume is at 20%
>
> Play the first track.
>
> When the track ends, and the second track is started, the volume goes
> to 100%

It seems that setting the volume to 100% can be done at a later stage?

I realise that I haven’t included the whole project here.
Also, initially I had included the above Java code just in one place – on the main activity’s OnCreate().
I then kept adding in more and more places, trying to see if it would ever take effect.

If any one has any ideas on what I might be doing wrong / or not doing, or has any questions – all feedback welcome thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct and your approach is also somewhat logical, but I see that you have tried this on only one device which limits your debugging. It is difficult to maintain volume level consistently at 100% on all the devices due to several factors like system settings, permissions, audio focus, and device-specific configurations. I would suggest you to try your code with multiple devices and see how they work.

Comment: It works on a Galaxy tablet. But I need to get it going on this Khadas device. There might be a way to do this by modifying the OS, but I would need to get someone else to do that at a later stage. In the meantime, I am just trying everything I can think of, from within the app, to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't manage to do this using Java from within the app.
In the end I had to get someone to modify & rebuild the Android OS